# Concordanza nel caso di più nomi

Tags: grammar

Buongiorno,

Mi è stata spedita questa email:

"Franco chiede l'ultima perdita di peso e test del colore su articolo A123"

Come va interpretata la frase?

Perdita di peso e test del colore sono due analisi di laboratorio. Entrambe vengono eseguite regolarmente e su molteplici articoli.

Le richieste si riferiscono entrambe all'articolo A123, oppure sono richieste: 1) l'ultima perdita di peso effettuata a prescindere dall'articolo, 2) il test del colore effettuato sull'articolo A123?

Grazie mille.

Comment: "Franco chiede l'ultima perdita di peso e test del colore su articolo A123" non sembra vero italiano (mancano alcuni articoli etc.). Probabilmente chi l'ha scritta l'ha fatto di fretta, o ci ha messo lo zampino un correttore ortografico. Forse faresti meglio a chiedere lumi al mittente.

Comment: Vero, scritta di fretta come si usa al lavoro. Io ho pensato che richiedesse entrambe le analisi per lo stesso articolo. Invece non era così. Vorrei sapere se ho sbagliato.

Comment: Per me il significato è ambiguo, faresti bene a chiedere delucidazioni al mittente.

Comment: Mi sono già chiarito col mittente. Volevo capire se ho sbagliato io ad interpretare la frase e se esiste una regola per questi casi.

Comment: La frase è effettivamente molto ambigua: si poteva benissimo capire in entrambi i modi. Chi chiede qualcosa farebbe bene a esprimersi chiaramente.